# Pushing Account Name (Local) to Scratch Org

Tags: salesforcedx, scratch-org

If I understand it correctly, Account Name (Local) in enabled by SF Support.
But in scratch orgs, it doesn't make sense to ask support for every new scratch org. Is there any way, how to enable the functionality to push the fields there? Thank you

Comment: I'd expect an option for this to be in orgPreferences in the Scratch Org Definition file but it's not there. I'd suggest you start an Idea for this.

Comment: Could also be worth posting in the Salesforce DX group in the Trailblazer Community; it's pretty active and often has some staff attention.

Comment: ok, thank you. The link to the idea is here https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000cRZJQA2